# getFiles() in react native with relayjs mutations

Tags: react-native, relayjs

I need to download multiple files from react native app throw relayjs mutation. Files array looks like:

`[
    {uri: 'file:///path/to/file.jpg', mime: 'image/jpg'},
    {uri: 'file:///path/to/file2.jpg', mime: 'image/jpg'},
]`

I found getFiles() func for mutations, but I don't understand what format of the data it should return?

Comment: getFiles receives an object, {'file1': file1, 'file2': file2}, where file1 is of File type. check Relay docs: https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-mutation.html#getfiles

Comment: What is File type in react-native?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Comment: u need to get a File from the uri, I guess. I'll dig into this in the next days

Comment: Someone solved the problem?

Comment: I've add my solution below, let me know if it was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I've solved it:

I used this package https://github.com/jeanpan/react-native-camera-roll-picker to get the image from the camera roll:

You can use it to test, add this to your render:

```
<CameraRollPicker
          callback={this.getSelectedImage}
          imagesPerRow={4}
          imageMargin={1}
          maximum={1}
        />
```

This is my implementation of getSelectedImage, I'm just sending one image, but you can send multiples images, files is an object where the value is an image.

```
getSelectedImage = (images) => {
    const image = images[0];

    const files = {
      [image.filename]: {
        uri: image.uri,
        name: image.filename,
      },
    };

    const mutation = new UploadUserProfileMutation({
      files,
    });

    this.props.relay.commitUpdate(mutation, callbacks);
  };
```

in your mutation add the method `getFiles`:

```
export default class UploadUserProfileMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
...
  getFiles() {
    return this.props.files;
  }
...
}
```

You should complete the mutation as a normal mutation

Comment: Ok, my `getFiles()` looks like `getFiles() {
    return {
      files: this.props.photo
    };
  }`  where this.props.photo = `{ photo0:{ uri:'file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20161015_054936.jpg', name: 'IMG_20161015_054936.jpg' } }` and i have an error "TypeError: Network request failed" and my server don't see any request. But when I remove getFiles func from my mutation, everything works ok. What's I do wrong?(

Comment: u need to set up a multer in your server to accept files